# How to edit the CSS of a div that does not contain a H1 tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There are two divs:

```
<div class="test">
<h1>This is a test</h1>
<p>Welcome to the test</p>
</div>

<div class="test">
<p>Welcome to the test</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, there are two divs which are in the same class however, one div has a H1 tag and the other div does not.

**CSS**:

```
.test {
font-size: 20px;
color: #fff
}
```

Above shows the CSS for the div `test`.

What I would like to do is apply additional CSS to the div that does not contain a H1 tag.

**If div contains a H1 tag:**

- Do nothing

**If div does NOT contain a H1 tag:**

- Apply the following CSS to that specific div

`font-size: 30px;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('.test:not(:has(h1))').css('font-size', '30px');
```

```css
.test {
font-size: 20px;
color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
<h1>This is a test</h1>
<p>Welcome to the test</p>
</div>

<div class="test">
<p>Welcome to the test</p>
</div>
```

You can use a selector with [:not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [:has](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) like

```
$('.test:not(:has(h1))').css('font-size', '30px');
```

Comment: @Arbel I included jQuery in the tags

Comment: Downvote for using JS to write CSS.  Thats just bad practice and not a solid answer.

Comment: @SeanStopnik, it is standard to use jQuery to write css all the time. It comes in use for dynamic situations or situations in which it is hard with pure css selectors. Do you mind shedding light on why this is bad practice?

Comment: First of all, its not 'standard' to write CSS in your JS.  Separation of markup and presentation is what we want.  The biggest reason to not use JS to write CSS is what happens to users who have their JS turned off?  In reality, the html should reflect what you are trying to style.  Give yourself an extra hook to target, such as: `.test.with-heading` or something like that.  You never want your css tied to your javascript, or vice versa.  Keep it separated.

Comment: @SeanStopnik, I have to say your argument is compelling and I never gave it too much thought. I need to research this more.

Answer (score 2):

Not really the best way of doing things, but if you CANNOT edit the html, then you can target the CSS by doing:

http://jsfiddle.net/42amv1xj/

```
.test {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

.test h1,
h1 ~ p {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

This is really wonky though!

Comment: not bad! I liked your keen eye on the use of an adjacent sibling selector